# Android Room: migration didn't properly handle crash - expected INTEGER found DATE

Tags: java, android, android-room, data-migration

Migration didn't properly handle CATALOG_MONTHLY(com.db.entities.CatalogMonthly).

Expected:

```
TableInfo{name='CATALOG_MONTHLY', columns={CATALOG_MONTHLY_TITLE=Column
{
name='CATALOG_MONTHLY_TITLE', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, 

CATALOG_IMAGE=Column{name='CATALOG_IMAGE', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},CATALOG_URL=Column{name='CATALOG_URL', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},CATALOG_MONTHLY_END_DATE=Column{name='**CATALOG_MONTHLY_END_DATE**', **type='INTEGER**', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, _id=Column{name='_id', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1},CATALOG_MONTHLY_START_DATE=Column{name='CATALOG_MONTHLY_START_DATE', **type='INTEGER'**, notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, CATALOG_MONTHLY_ORDER=Column{name='CATALOG_MONTHLY_ORDER', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},CATALOG_DESCRIPTION=Column{name='CATALOG_DESCRIPTION', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

Found:

```
TableInfo{name='CATALOG_MONTHLY', columns={CATALOG_MONTHLY_TITLE=Column{
name='CATALOG_MONTHLY_TITLE', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
 CATALOG_IMAGE=Column{name='CATALOG_IMAGE', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, CATALOG_URL=Column{name='CATALOG_URL', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},CATALOG_MONTHLY_END_DATE=Column{name='**CATALOG_MONTHLY_END_DATE**', **type='DATE'**, notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, _id=Column{name='_id', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1},CATALOG_MONTHLY_ORDER=Column{name='CATALOG_MONTHLY_ORDER', type='INTEGER', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, CATALOG_MONTHLY_START_DATE=Column{name='CATALOG_MONTHLY_START_DATE', type='DATE', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, CATALOG_DESCRIPTION=Column{name='CATALOG_DESCRIPTION', type='TEXT', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

From the log, I got to know that there is difference in the type for CATALOG_MONTHLY_END_DATE key which was supposed to be integer but it found as Integer.

But from the old db side, value for CATALOG_MONTHLY_END_DATE is being converted to integer from date during migration. So I am not sure how exactly to solve this crash.